# How to center a panel with icon and wrapped(!) text with CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

Is it possible to center the content (icon + text) within the container horizontally and vertically, if the text happens to wrap? It seems that CSS engine does not calculate a visible width of the wrapped text and my current solution does not work... Please look at this https://jsfiddle.net/wabrm1st/

html:

```
  <a href=# class="box">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="text">How can I center when_it_wrapped?</span>
  </a>
```

css:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 30px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.icon {
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  background: #edc;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Maybe, it is possible to calculate the width of the wrapped text in JavaScript?

Comment: There are a few ways to solve this. You could wrap the icon and the text in another div then center that. Flexbox might be helpful here depending on how you implement it.

Comment: Try to look at this: http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

Comment: @jeanpier_re I think I've already tried everything, including <table> ;-) Text should be wrapped only when it does not fit one line... Could you update my JSFiddler sample with a working solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick workup of the solution I mentioned earlier. I'll see if I can clean it up and make it more optimal later. If you want to avoid using flexbox you can use `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;`. Again, I'll see if I can send you that solution later as well.

```css
.container {
  width: 220px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box{
    width: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  height: 40%;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.text {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="box">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="text">How can I center when_it_wrapped?</span>
  </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work. Try set the width of your container to 220px for example, then the text wraps and becomes not centered any more. This was my original question: how to center _wrapped_ text.

Comment: Actually it does work, you'd just need to modify the code to be flexible to different sizes. This was more of a proof of concept, but I've updated the answer to work at various widths

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Try to set the width of container to 130px and text are not wrapped, icon squeezes; then try to set it to 390px and distance between icon and text goes to big, and text is not left aligned. All I need is to center the box within a container, but the box has an icon and a left aligned text which can wrap. If you think any solution exists, please update the original [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wabrm1st/) which animates the width of container to demonstrate if solution works.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking but it its why the text isn't center aligned when the container gets smaller (lowest size in that animation) then it's a simple `display: inline-block` here is a fork of your jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/deu4um3y/

Comment: I must be really bad asker :) but I do not need the distance between the icon and the text to change. The text should start right after the icon and when wrapped in two lines it should be left aligned to the icon as in my original jsfiddle. What needs to be centered is the [icons + text] as a whole. I have added a third box to show what I want as a result, please check: [jsfiddle.net/wabrm1st/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/wabrm1st/2/)